# use the elements of ngfor in ngif

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

Current Behavior: See the code below.

Behavior wish: I would simply like to use ngfor elements to make comparison in ngif.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of userspeList" >
            <div *ngFor="let rspe of rspeList" >


              <div *ngIf="item?.uid === rspe?.uid; then adan">

                   <p>Je suis le plus grand</p>
              </div>


                <ng-template #adan>
                     {{item.uid}} and {{rspe.uid}}
                </ng-template>

            </div>

      </div>
```

The browser displays the ng template with:

```
   PFbrvtxABEeXKhRMH2RaWnSkq0g1 and PFbrvtxABEeXKhRMH2RaWnSkq0g1.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you provide a [mcve] on stackblitz?

Comment: I think what is going wrong is `(item)?.uid == (rspe)?.uid` this can seems to be async and what happen is  `PFbrvtxABEeXKhRMH2RaWnSkq0g1 and undifned` on the check and the it will change cause of the two way binding. What you have to do is check if both values are not undefined or changed. But if change again you need to have some kind of value that tell you both promises are done.

Answer (score 3):

You have only one ng-template, hence you can use else

```
<div *ngIf="(item)?.uid === (rspe)?.uid ; else adan">
  {{item.uid}} and {{rspe.uid}}
</div>

<ng-template #adan>
  <p>Je suis le plus grand</p>
</ng-template>
```

Please take look at https://toddmotto.com/angular-ngif-else-then

One more problem with your code is, if condition fails it wont display

```
<p>Je suis le plus grand</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the identity (===) operator along with `else`

```
<div *ngIf="item?.uid === rspe?.uid; else adan">
```